# Blackberry PictureScrollField image issue when focus is removed

Tags: blackberry, java-me, onfocus, lost-focus, picturegallery

I'm using a `PictureScrollField` in a `VerticalFieldManager` with other fields that need focus. When the `PictureScrollField` receives focus, the images are shown in their original form. But when I remove focus, by default, the field draws a white square over the images. I looked around in the API and couldn't find a way to undo this default property. How to remove these squares?

This is the image when the field has focus-

[image: This is the image when the field has focus]

And this is when the field loses focus-

[image]

You can see how the images have white overlays which look bad for non rectangular transparent images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is pretty simple - override `onUnfocus` method as

```
protected void onUnfocus(){
    /*do nothing to prevent BB default image highlight*/
    /*or do your own thing*/
}
```